# Declare pointer inside a function that is called several times

Tags: c++, loops, pointers, declare

I would like to know whether or not I can do this with a function Idle() which is called several times in an opengl program.Is this OK or will I get a memory leak?

```
void Idle()
{
    //PXCPointF32 is a struct
    PXCPointF32 *uvmap=0;

    uvmap=new PXCPointF32[640*480];
    if(uvmap!=NULL)
    {
       //do some processing
       //fill uvmap values
    }

    if (uvmap) 
    {
        delete[] uvmap;
        uvmap=NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's OK, but I don't like your inconsistency: `0`/`NULL` (use `nullptr`), `if(uvmap != NULL)` is the same as `if(uvmap)`. The second version is preferred, since pointers are implicitly convertible to `bool`. You also don't need to set `uvmap` to `NULL` after freeing the memory since it's local.

Comment: Yes you can do it, but *why* ? `std::vector<PXCPointF32> uvmap(640*480);`, then use `uvmap[]` as needed. And since this is a callback, I *strongly* advise you try-catch for  `const std::exception&`. You don't want to let an allocation failure (or any other `std::exception` derivative) throw back to unknown code. Read more about coding using [RAII here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization).

Comment: Because later on, the SDK I use has a function which takes as an argument a pointer to PXCPointF32 and fills up the uvmap.What do I do there if I use a vector? I just pass the pointer to the 1st element of the vector?

Comment: Can I use &uvmap[0] to pass as argument if I use vectors as you said?

Comment: Yes you can. Alternatively, I concur with Bill, If this is critical for performance and has *no chance* of concurrency issues, a static buffer will easily beat everything else. Those are *big* if's, but worth consideration. If you decide dynamic allocation is required, there still-more considerations depending on what a PXCPointF32 actually is. If it is a plain-old-data type and initialization isn't important (because you're going to overwrite the data anyway) then Galik's answer may be more appropriate (the smart-pointer approach, btw).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should work but its not optimal:

```
void Idle()
{
    //PXCPointF32 is a struct
    PXCPointF32 *uvmap=0; // why initialize to 0 only to replace its value?

    uvmap=new PXCPointF32[640*480];
    if(uvmap!=NULL)
    {
       //do some processing
       //fill uvmap values
    }

    if (uvmap) // no need to test for null before deleting
    {
        delete[] uvmap;
        uvmap=NULL; // no point setting to NULL because its local
    }
}
```

Instead you could do:

```
void Idle()
{
    // set it directly
    PXCPointF32* uvmap = new PXCPointF32[640*480];

    if(uvmap)
    {
       //do some processing
       //fill uvmap values
    }

    delete[] uvmap; // don't bother checking for null (delete[] does that)
}
```

You might also want to consider a smart pointer to clean up the memory in case of an exception:

```
void Idle()
{
    // set it directly
    std::unique_ptr<PXCPointF32[]> uvmap(new PXCPointF32[640*480]);

    if(uvmap)
    {
       //do some processing
       //fill uvmap values
    }

    // no delete[] here
}
```

Comment: If I use a unique_ptr though, after that I have a function which takes as an argument a  PXCPointF32 Pointer. So what do I do there>? Can I cast it?

Comment: @Mario13 You can simple pass it the managed pointer using `my_function(uvmap.get());`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason for a memory leak. But it is not really fine art programming. In such a situation I would prefer to reserve memory once at start of the program and hold it until end of the program to avoid memory fragmentation and speed penalties.
Also the code has some "cargo" lines:

```
void Idle()
{
//PXCPointF32 is a struct
PXCPointF32 *uvmap=new PXCPointF32[640*480];

if(uvmap==NULL)
{
  // panic and return 
}

//do some processing
//fill uvmap values

delete[] uvmap;
//    uvmap=NULL;  out of scope anyway
}
```

Comment: I think you have forgotten the `new` operator.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine that this function is called as part of a GUI thread. That means that I don't need to worry about multiple threads accessing this function simultaneously.

So then let's just allocate the memory statically.

```
void Idle()
{
    //PXCPointF32 is a struct
    static PXCPointF32 uvmap[640*480];

    //do some processing
    //fill uvmap values
}
```

This code can't leak memory (because it doesn't allocate any). Your code is also fine, as long as nothing in `Idle()` launches an exception.

Comment: That can be problematic on a low-resource system. Also, if similar approach is taken in the rest of the code it can become a problem on a regular system as well

Answer (score 0):

That will not leak unless an exception is thrown before the delete and after the new. Using a smart pointer will prevent this.